# SwiftUI replacing @State Binding<Int> with data from @ObservedObject

Tags: swiftui, binding, state, observedobject

I have imported a a confettiCannon code for my app, which needs a binding Int in the view to be executed.

https://github.com/simibac/ConfettiSwiftUI#-installation

```
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var game: Game
    @State private var counter: Int = 0

var body: some View {
        HStack { }.frame(height: 140)
                  .onTapGesture { counter += 1 }
                  .confettiCannon(counter: $counter)
                    }
```

Instead of using the @State var, I would like to use the animation when a value in my game data changes (which is an ObservedObject):

```
.confettiCannon(counter: $game.counter)
```

But this leads to the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type
> 'Binding'

What needs to be adapted to make this connection work?

Comment: Modifying the variable as get/set did the trick.

class Game: ObservableObject {
    var counter: Int {
            get { return data.counter}
            set { }
        }
}

Answer (score 0):

works well for me with the following example code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import ConfettiSwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var game = Game() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        MyView(game: game) // <-- here
    }
}

class Game: ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter: Int = 0 // <-- here
}

struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var game: Game
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("tap me for confetti")
        }.frame(height: 140)
            .onTapGesture { game.counter += 1 }
            .confettiCannon(counter: $game.counter)
    }
}
```